# How to select many distinct elements on List<Dictionary<string, string>>?

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to select entries in a list of dictionaries in order to create a new dictionary containing only distinct items necessary for me.

For example, starting with this list:

```csharp
List<Dictionary<string, string>> test = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>{            
    new Dictionary<string, string>{{"labelGroup", "Livret A"}, {"idtGroupe", "idtLivretA"}, {"variables", "test1"}},
    new Dictionary<string, string>{{"labelGroup", "Livret B"}, {"idtGroupe", "idtLivretB"}, {"variables", "test2"}},
    new Dictionary<string, string>{{"labelGroup", "Livret A"}, {"idtGroupe", "idtLivretA"}, {"variables", "test1"}},
    new Dictionary<string, string>{{"labelGroup", "Livret B"}, {"idtGroupe", "idtLivretB"}, {"variables", "test2"}},
    new Dictionary<string, string>{{"labelGroup", "Livret A"}, {"idtGroupe", "idtLivretA"}, {"variables", "test1"}},
    new Dictionary<string, string>{{"labelGroup", "Livret A"}, {"idtGroupe", "idtLivretA"}, {"variables", "test1"}},
    new Dictionary<string, string>{{"labelGroup", "Livret A"}, {"idtGroupe", "idtLivretA"}, {"variables", "test1"}},
    new Dictionary<string, string>{{"labelGroup", "Livret A"}, {"idtGroupe", "idtLivretA"}, {"variables", "test1"}},
    new Dictionary<string, string>{{"labelGroup", "Livret A"}, {"idtGroupe", "idtLivretA"}, {"variables", "test1"}},
    new Dictionary<string, string>{{"labelGroup", "Livret B"}, {"idtGroupe", "idtLivretB"}, {"variables", "test2"}},
    new Dictionary<string, string>{{"labelGroup", "Livret A"}, {"idtGroupe", "idtLivretA"}, {"variables", "test1"}},
    new Dictionary<string, string>{{"labelGroup", "Livret A"}, {"idtGroupe", "idtLivretA"}, {"variables", "test1"}},
    new Dictionary<string, string>{{"labelGroup", "Livret A"}, {"idtGroupe", "idtLivretA"}, {"variables", "test1"}},
};
```

I would like to have a new dictionary without the key "variables" and that contains :

```js
{"labelGroup", "Livret A"},
{"idtGroupe", "idtLivretA"},
{"labelGroup", "Livret B"},
{"idtGroupe", "idtLivretB"}
```

Comment: What return type would that be?

Comment: What is a special rule for key `"variables"`? You only mention it in expected output, but not among your requirements at the top of your question.

Comment: When you want to get a new Dictionary as a result your example result won't work because you already have duplicate keys "labelGroup" and "idtGroupe". The only possible way of resolving this would be to create a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` and your result could look like `{"labelGroup", ["Livret A", "Livret B"]}, {"idtGroupe", ["idtLivretA", "idtLivretB"]}`

Comment: Do you mean you want a new `List<Dictionary<..,..>>`? Also, do you mean you have values in range  `Livret [A-Z]` and `dtLivret[A-Z]`? Because, with the sample here, just a `.SelectMany(d => d.Where(kv => kv.Key != "variables"))` will filter as described. Do you need custom filters *on deman* (on user selection) or something similar? Filtering on values is not great.

Comment: @Jimi sorry, didnt saw your comment so i posted similiar thing as answer

Comment: @Djuro  It's all right. I was just asking for clarifications, so someone can post an answer that fits the actual requirements. I'll remove the comment(s) when it's all done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Distinct()` method. You have to iterate on your list of dictionary for each key. Your output has to be list of dictionary otherwise you will encounter duplicate key issue.

```cs
            var distinctDictionary = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

            foreach (var keyItem in test.First().Keys)
            {
                if (keyItem == "variables")
                    continue;

                var tempDistinct = (from t in test select t[keyItem]).Distinct();

                foreach (var distinctItem in tempDistinct)
                {
                    distinctDictionary.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { keyItem, distinctItem } });
                }
            }
```

If your test dictionary is empty, `First()` method will throw an exception. You may want to check if it is empty or not before iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Answer above is good, but you can do that with simple one liner.

> ```
>         var distincts = test.SelectMany(x => x).Where(x=> x.Key != "variables").Distinct();
> ```

SelectMany() will select all items from you dictionaries and join to one Dictionary

Distinct() - easy one, this will select distinct items